# QFileDialog preselect directory

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

i have a QFileDialog object where i need the user to select a directory

```
QFileDialog dlg(this, tr("Select directory"));
dlg.setDirectory(currentDir);
dlg.setFileMode(QFileDialog::Directory);
dlg.setOptions(QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly | QFileDialog::ReadOnly);
```

my folder structure is for example

```
<root>
  <dir1>
  <dir2>
```

when the `currentDir` is `<root>/dir1` i want the dialog to point on the `<root>` dir and select `dir1` in the dialog (not only in text form but also like when you have clicked it)

is that possible, and how?

/edit:
i tried

```
dlg.setDirectory("<root>");
dlg.selectFile("dir1");
```

that resulted in the dialog to set the correct directory and fill the `filename` line edit but does not select it in the list of files (but thats quite needed when having a lot of similar dir names).

cheers

Comment: I tried several things with `QFileDialog` but it did not work. Qt 5.6.0 here, though. Using `QUrl` did not change the behaviour. Neither the selection is adjusted nor the text box filled. This might be a bug. Also adjusting some flags without success. As the documentation says `selectFile` should be the way. Maybe there is an issue here.

Answer (score 1):

[selectFile()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#selectFile) should do the trick:

```
QFileDialog dlg(this, tr("Select directory"));

if(currentDir == "<root>/dir1") {
    dlg.selectFile(currentDir);
}
else {
    dlg.setDirectory(currentDir);
}

dlg.setFileMode(QFileDialog::Directory);
dlg.setOptions(QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly | QFileDialog::ReadOnly);
```

Comment: nice but thats only half of the problem. see edit in question

Comment: Did you try to set the file mode before selectFile()?

Comment: yes; basically you take my first code snippet and add the edit stuff